# Consulta SQL para obtener el conteo de registro por estados de proceso

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo una tabla la cual ceunta con una estructura similar a la siguiente

```
+----------+------+-----------+----------------+---------------+----------+
|procesoid | tipo | usuarioid | departamentoid | estadotramite | fecha    |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1         |1    |  1        |  1             |     1         |2019-11-18 |
|2         | 1   |  2        |  1             |     1         |2019-11-18 |
|3         | 1   |  3        |  1             |     1         |2019-11-18 |
|4         | 1   |  1        |  2             |     2         |2019-11-20 |
|5         | 1   |  2        |  2             |     2         |2019-11-20 |
|6         | 1   |  3        |  2             |     2         |2019-11-20 |
|7         | 1   |  1        |  3             |     3         |2019-11-22 |
|8         | 1   |  2        |  3             |     3         |2019-11-22 |
|9         | 1   |  3        |  3             |     3         |2019-11-22 |
|10        | 1   |  1        |  3             |     4         |2019-11-25 |
+----------+-----+-----------+----------------+---------------+-----------+
```

donde los valosres de la columan aestado tramite se define de la siguiente manera

```
estadotramite 
1 iniciado
2 proceso
3 validando             
4 terminado
```

requiero obtener cuantos usuarios se encuentra en cada etapa de estado tramite, intente realizarlo con la siguiente consulta

```
select 
coalesce( sum((case when estadotramite between 1  and 1 then 1 else 0 end) ) ,0) as iniciado,
coalesce( sum((case when estadotramite between 2  and 2 then 1 else 0 end) ) ,0) as proceso, 
coalesce( sum((case when estadotramite between 3  and 3 then 1 else 0 end) ) ,0) as validando,
coalesce( sum((case when estadotramite between 4  and 4 then 1 else 0 end) ) ,0) as terminado
from proceso ;

+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| iniciado | proceso | vaidando   | terminado |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
|        3 |       3 |          3 |         1 |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

asi mismo con la siguiente consula

```
select 
count(distinct (case egresadoid when estadotramite between 1 and 1  then 1 else 0 end)) as iniciado,
count(distinct (case egresadoid when estadotramite between 2 and 2  then 1 else 0 end)) as proceso,
count(distinct (case egresadoid when estadotramite between 3 and 3  then 1 else 0 end)) as validando,
count(distinct (case egresadoid when estadotramite between 4 and 4  then 1 else 0 end)) as terminado
from proceso;

+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| iniciado | proceso | vaidando   | terminado |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
|        1 |       1 |          3 |         3 |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

mas el resultado deseado seria es el siguiente

```
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| iniciado | proceso | vaidando   | terminado |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
|        0 |       0 |          2 |         1 |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

a lo cual acudo a la comunidad pidiendo ayuda u orientacion para obtener el resultado deseado, agradeciendo anticipadamente sus respuestas y sugerencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para llegar al resultado deseado vamos a realizar unos pequeños cambios en el código planteado.

**Primero:**

Vamos a realizar una subconsulta para recuperar el último estado por cada usuario de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT max(estadotramite) estado, usuarioid FROM proceso
GROUP BY usuarioid
```

**Segundo:**

En vez del `Count` vamos a utilizar el `Sum` para acumular los estados.

```
SUM( CASE WHEN c.estado = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) iniciado, ...
```

La consulta queda de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN c.estado = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) iniciado,
       SUM( CASE WHEN c.estado = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) proceso,
       SUM( CASE WHEN c.estado = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) validando,
       SUM( CASE WHEN c.estado = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) terminado
FROM(
    SELECT max(estadotramite) estado, usuarioid FROM proceso
    GROUP BY usuarioid
) AS c;
```

**El resultado:**

```
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
| iniciado | proceso | validando  | terminado |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
|        0 |       0 |          2 |         1 |
+----------+---------+------------+-----------+
```